# Returning a concrete implementation as a generic

Tags: c#, oop, generics, generic-programming, bogus

I have an interface which looks like this:

```
public interface IFaker
{
    Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class;
}

public class DogFaker : IFaker
{
    public Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new Faker<Dog>()
            .RuleFor(dog => dog.Name, f => f.Name.FirstName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(dog => dog.IsGoodBoy, f => f.Random.Bool());
    }
}
```

The problem is - I can't return a `Faker<Dog>` in place of `Faker<T>` e.g

`Bogus.Faker<_scratchpad.models.Dog>' to 'Bogus.Faker<T>`

Obviously I can't change `new Faker<Dog>` to `new Faker<T>` because then I can't access the Dog properties.

I want to use the object like so:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _fakers;

public FakerService()
{
    _fakers = InitialiseFakers();
}

private Dictionary<string, object> InitialiseFakers()
{
   return new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {typeof(Dog).FullName, new DogFaker().GetFaker<Dog>()}
    };
}

public IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(int count) where T : class
{
    var faker = GetFaker<T>();
    return faker.Generate(count);
}

private Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class
{
    var faker = (Faker<T>)_fakers[typeof(T).FullName];
    return faker;
}
```

Comment: Also, consider changing the `Key` of your `Dictionary` to be `Type` rather than `string`.

Comment: I wasn't actually too happy with my dictionary - any other tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest starting with:

```
public interface IFaker<T> where T : class
{
    Faker<T> GetFaker();
}

public class DogFaker : IFaker<Dog>
{
    public Faker<Dog> GetFaker() 
    {
        return new Faker<Dog>()
        // whatever else you need here
        ;
    }
}
```

This way `DogFaker.GetFaker()` has its `T` constraint defined **explicitly** as `Dog` - rather than it being defined by the caller.